# Do i need to load javascript again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I m adding a row in a table via jquery. Every row has some javascript associated with it.
When i add a new row using jquery, the javasccript works on previous rows, but not on newly added row.

**Do i need to load the same js again ?? if yes, how?**

**js works on already html row, but not on row i added**

```
<table>
    <tr id="hello12">
        <div class="formField" style="float:right" >
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" >
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add Attachments...</span>
                <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="attachment" multiple>
            </span>
        </div>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>
            <button type="button" id="override_button">
                <b>+</b>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/attachments/create',
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
       alert("done");
    },

});

 $('#override_button').click(function(){
   alert("hello")

$('#hello12').after('\ <tr id="hello12">
        <div class="formField" style="float:right" >
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" >
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add Attachments...</span>
                <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="attachment" multiple>
            </span>
        </div>
    </tr>')
});
```

Comment: Yes you do. We can't tell you how for certain without seeing your code. You either need to re-attach the events, or use delegated event handlers.

Comment: just tell me how to load the js again after adding one row to table? how does that links with code..

Comment: just show us your code and we would help. your question is more likely to get closed unless you post some of your codes here just to let you know.

Comment: Asking question regarding specific code ***without*** posting relevant code in question is quite silly, isn't it?? Maybe yes, maybe no, who knows???

Comment: We meant your JS code which is attaching your event handlers in the first instance.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan maybe OP is already delegating any event, again, who knows? ;)  EDIT: so no.*...

Comment: OP, AGAIN, we need to see the code which is ***attaching the events***

Comment: may be jquery is ataching itself :P

Comment: I hope my question gets upvotes now.. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Finally after lot of struggle i got the answer,

Fileupload binds the action to the html once it is loaded, so if you add a new html to the page ,
for each element you have to bind the fileupload again.( you can also use live action to add events to button, in that case you do not need to bind again)

```
var dofileupload = function(){
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
url: '/attachments/create',
dataType: 'json',
done: function (e, data) {
   alert("done");
},
});
}

$('#override_button').click(function(){
alert("hello")

$('#hello12').after('\ <tr id="hello12">
    <div class="formField" style="float:right" >
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" >
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add Attachments...</span>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="attachment" multiple>
        </span>
    </div>
</tr>')
}).each(function () {
 dofileupload
}
```

`This solves my problem`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on` jquery function :

```
$("table").on("click", "#override_button", function(event){
    alert("done");
});
```

or if you use jquery prior to 1.7 check `live` function

example: http://jsfiddle.net/rad_101/99q5jwrx/1/

Comment: but i need js to be loaded again and the listener is on row, cant add it to table

Comment: I created an example, i change a bit your code. But the main idea is the `on` function
http://jsfiddle.net/rad_101/99q5jwrx/

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: You are hard-bound to reload the script(which I donot feel is a necessity at all). You can save the script in an external file, and append it to the head of your html page.

```
<script language="text/javascript">
   function load_js()
   {
      var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script= document.createElement('script');
      script.type= 'text/javascript';
      script.src= 'source_file.js';
      head.appendChild(script);
   }

   // call the function, so as to run the scripts again on the page
   load_js();
</script>
```

Case 2: (More efficiently) Use (as Dimitris Nastos pointed out)

```
      $(document).on("click", "table .row", function(){
         //write your "ASSOCIATED JS" code here.
      });
```

This binds a click event to the document and all child elements within it. It then matches the element identifier provided as the second argument. Works on dynamic elements too.

Case 3: (Little more efficiently) In your case, table is a static element, and would the parent element of the new row. Hence, instead of traversing the whole DOM while writing $(document).on("click","element",function(){}), use

```
      $(table).on("click", "table .row", function(){
         //write your "ASSOCIATED JS" code here.
      });
```